# Translating an NPM into a gulp task

Tags: html, node.js, npm, gulp

My gulp file produces sets of html files using Nunjucks. I want to use those files to output some html to text files. I found an NPM that turns html file to text but I"m not 100% sure how or if I can use this inside a gulp task. The module is [html-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text) and I'm trying to use it like this:

```
var html2text = require('html-to-text');
gulp.task('html2text',function(){
  return gulp.src('build/*.html')
  .pipe(html2text.fromFile())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/txt'))
});
```

Obviously it's complaining about not getting a file to translate to txt. I feel like this should be doable but I'm not super well versed with gulpfiles yet.

Comment: Seems trivial with https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nunjucks

Comment: To be compatible with `.pipe()`, perhaps you need to implement a transform stream.  https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I have a directory with sets of html that need to covert to text. I'm using the Nunjucks templating system to create the html. I can't use the same files to also create the text versions since they have a template they already use in the html process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var glob = require('glob-fs')({ gitignore: true });
var html2text = require('html-to-text');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('default', function () {

  glob.readdirStream('build/*.html')
    .on('data', function (file) {
      console.log(file.path);

      html2text.fromFile(file.path, (err, text) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

        // strip off extension and parent directories
        var filename = path.basename(file.path, '.html');

        // I assume you want a.html text to be written to 'build/txt/a.txt'
        fs.writeFileSync(path.join('build/txt', filename  + '.txt'), text, 'utf8');
      });
   });
});
```

You don't have to use gulp.src and gulp.dest and work with streams in a gulp task if you don't want to.  The above task globs your files one-by-one and operates on them individually, sending each file name to the html2text function.

See the [glob-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-fs) package.